# Set top row and left column for an XSSFSheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to make sure an XLSX sheet is at the top left when the file is open.

The `XSSFSheet` has a [`getTopCol()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getTopRow()) and a [`getLeftCol()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getLeftCol()) methods, but there is no setter.

[`XSSFSheet.showInPane(int, int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#showInPane(int,%20int)) does work, but only if pane is frozen or split.

```
    PaneInformation pane = sheet.getPaneInformation();
    if (pane == null) {
        // FIXME doesn't work when there is no pane
        sheet.showInPane(CellAddress.A1.getRow(), CellAddress.A1.getColumn());
    } else {
        // OK
        sheet.showInPane(pane.getHorizontalSplitPosition(), pane.getVerticalSplitPosition());
    }
```

I tried to view what could be accessed from the XSSFSheet class, but all underlying methods are private.

Does anybody know of a way to reset the view of a sheet to the top left cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if there is not such setting directly with the `POI` objects. But it is possible  with `CTWorksheet`. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorksheet.java#CTWorksheet

```
...
((XSSFSheet)sheet).getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0).setTopLeftCell("D10");
...
```

Best possibility getting such informations is creating a simple file directly with `Excel`. Then save this as `*.xlsx`. Then unzip this file and look in `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`. There you find:

```
...
<sheetViews>
 <sheetView workbookViewId="0" tabSelected="true" topLeftCell="D10"/>
</sheetViews>
...
```

Comment: Sorry for the hold-up. So, if I summarize here, your suggestion would be to edit the XMLs myself? Too bad for me: I chose POI in the hope of avoiding that. :)

Comment: @Chop: No, I've provided a code line which sets the `TopLeftCell` for a `XSSFSheet`. My suggestion to have a look at the `XML` should show you how you can get informations of what is possible.

Comment: I don't even know why I missed this. I had found this method by exploring the sources but was convinced it was `private`. Thanks! (This is one of these times when I feel ridiculous).

Answer (score 0):

*To add some more background on this:*

If you look at the respective implementations of [`getTopRow()`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup&revision=1724469#l1425) and [`getLeftCol()`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup&revision=1724469#l1042) they both get their values from an instance of `CTSheetView` (via two different ways which, I suppose, is not completely intentional).

In contrast, [`showInPane()`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup&revision=1724469#l2933) is based on a `CTPane` which is a data structure that lives one level below a `CTSheetView`. According to [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-376,%20Fourth%20Edition,%20Part%201%20-%20Fundamentals%20And%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.zip) (page 3904) such a `CTPane` is optional (i.e. you do not have to apply a "split" to your `CTSheetView`).

However, what remains dubious to me is the following: `showInPane()` (via [`getPane()`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup&revision=1724469#l3183)) does, in fact, try to create a new pane if there is none, yet. On this new pane it then calls `setTopLeftCell()` - which according to ECMA-376 (page 1657) only applies to a *bottom right pane*. The default type of a new pane is *top left*, though (see page 2460 of that spec for a list of available panes).

This means:

- There may be an error in that monstrous ECMA-376 spec. So setting the top left cell is actually possible for all pane types.
- POI probably contains a bug somewhere around the `getPane()`-method which prevents it from actually inserting a new pane into the sheet view.

... for a pragmatic solution how to get around this you should stick to Axel Richter's answer, though. This sets the visible cells directly on the `CTSheetView` which is most likely what you are after.