# Is there any way to move horizontal scroll bar the sheet one column to the left using POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have written a program that reads Excel template sheet. In which the first column was hidden. Now, I have a code that un-hide the excel column programmatically (so Column start from A1).

I'm using Apache POI 3.16 version.

When I open a file, it should show me a column from A1 instead it shows me from B1 column.
When I write below code for XLS, It working properly but didn't work for an XLSX format.

```
sheet.showInPane(0, 0);
```

I need to manually move the horizontal scroll bar to view my first column. How should I achieve this programmatically to auto-scroll to the first column for XLSX format?

Here is my full code.

```
public Workbook readWorkBookAndWriteErrors(String bufId,String inputFile, String ext) throws Exception {
        Workbook workBook =null;
        Sheet sheet = null; 
        if(GlobalVariables.EXCEL_FORMAT_XLS.equalsIgnoreCase(ext)){
             // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        }else{
            // Get the workbook instance for XLSX file
            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        }
        sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = null;
        if(sheet.isColumnHidden(0)){
            sheet.setColumnHidden(0, false);
            sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress("A1"));
            sheet.showInPane(0, 0);
            sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);

             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                int rowIndex = 1;
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    row = rowIterator.next();
                    if(rowIndex == 1){
                        rowIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                    cell.setCellValue("error message");
                    rowIndex++;
                }
        }
        return workBook;
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974778/set-top-row-and-left-column-for-an-xssfsheet/

Comment: Thanks @Axel Richter

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to my question. Please refer this  [Source](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/showInPane-does-not-work-td5720321.html)

```
public Workbook readWorkBookAndWriteErrors(String bufId,String inputFile, String ext) throws Exception {
        Workbook workBook =null;
        Sheet sheet = null; 
        if(GlobalVariables.EXCEL_FORMAT_XLS.equalsIgnoreCase(ext)){
             // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        }else{
            // Get the workbook instance for XLSX file
            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        }
        sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = null;
        if(sheet.isColumnHidden(0)){
            sheet.setColumnHidden(0, false);

            if(sheet instanceof XSSFSheet){
                CTWorksheet ctWorksheet = null; 
                CTSheetViews ctSheetViews = null; 
                CTSheetView ctSheetView = null; 
                XSSFSheet tempSheet = (XSSFSheet) sheet;
                 // First step is to get at the CTWorksheet bean underlying the worksheet. 
                ctWorksheet = tempSheet.getCTWorksheet(); 
                // From the CTWorksheet, get at the sheet views. 
                ctSheetViews = ctWorksheet.getSheetViews(); 
                // Grab a single sheet view from that array 
                ctSheetView = ctSheetViews.getSheetViewArray(ctSheetViews.sizeOfSheetViewArray() - 1); 
                // Se the address of the top left hand cell. 
                ctSheetView.setTopLeftCell("A1"); 
            }else{
                 sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress("A1"));
                 sheet.showInPane(0, 0);
            }


             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                int rowIndex = 1;
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    row = rowIterator.next();
                    if(rowIndex == 1){
                        rowIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                    cell.setCellValue("error message");
                    rowIndex++;
                }
        }
        return workBook;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest C# NPOI, I made this utility function:

```
/// <summary>Set view position at given coordinates.</summary>
/// <param name="sheet">A reference to the Excel sheet.</param>
/// <param name="topLeftCell">The coordinates of the cell that will show in top left corner when you open the Excel sheet (example: "A1").</param>
/// <param name="onlyFirstView">If true, only first sheet view will have position adjusted. If false, every views from the sheet will have have position adjusted.</param>
public static void SetViewPosition(ref NPOI.SS.UserModel.ISheet sheet, string topLeftCell = "A1", bool onlyFirstView = true)
{
    NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Spreadsheet.CT_Worksheet worksheet = (NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Spreadsheet.CT_Worksheet)(typeof(NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFSheet).GetField("worksheet", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue((NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFSheet)sheet));
    if (worksheet?.sheetViews?.sheetView != null && worksheet.sheetViews.sheetView.Count > 0)
    {
        if (onlyFirstView)
            worksheet.sheetViews.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = topLeftCell;
        else
            foreach (NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Spreadsheet.CT_SheetView view in worksheet.sheetViews.sheetView)
                view.topLeftCell = topLeftCell;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
NPOI.SS.UserModel.ISheet mySheet = myWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
// First sheet from our workbook opens with view set to top left corner (cell A1 visible in top left corner).
SetViewPosition(ref mySheet, "A1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me to move horizontal scrollbar to required position.

Used apache poi libraries(poi, poi-ooxml).

((XSSFSheet)sheet).getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0).setTopLeftCell("AE11");